# Spring data couchbase, unable to delete the document by id using reactive programming

Tags: reactive-programming, couchbase, spring-webflux

Recently we decided to use spring-webflux with couchbase in our project, and we need help on how to solve below use case in reactive programming

1. Validate and save the request in Bucket1 couchbase ,(we used javax.validation, and spring ReactiveCouchbaseRepository.
2. Call external service (we used webclient to call the API.

   - Upon successful,

     - write AUDIT document to Bucket2.
     - Fetch the document that is inserted in Bucket1 and send the same in response.
     - write Audit document to Bucket2
   - Upon failure,

     - write AUDIT document to Bucket2.
     - delete the document that is inserted in BUCKET1 and throw the exception.
     - write Audit document to Bucket2

We have written a service class, and are using two repository classes to save the documents to couchbase, and a webclient to call external service.

Our service class method business logic looks like below.

```
    {

    //1. Validate the request and throw the error
    List<String> validationMessages = handler.validate(customerRequest);
    if (validationMessages != null && !validationMessages.isEmpty()) {
        return Mono.error(new InvalidRequestException("Invalid Request", validationMessages, null));
    }

    //generate the id, set it to the request and save it to BUCKET1
    String customerRequestId = sequenceGenerator.nextId(Sequence.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID);
    customerRequest.setcustomerRequestId(customerRequestId);
    customerRequestMono = bucket1Repository.save(customerRequest);


    //2. Call the external service using webclient
    externalServiceResponse = customerRequestWebClient.createCFEEnrollment(customerRequest);

    //2. Subscribe to the response and and on Success write audit to BUCKET2 , and onerror write audit to BUCKET2 , and delete the inserted documet from BUCKET1
    externalServiceResponse.subscribe(response -> {
        //Initialise the success audit bean and save
        //2.1 a) Write Audt to BUCKET2
        Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(cfeAudit);
         }, errorResp -> {
        //2.2 a) Write Audt to BUCKET2
        //Initialise the error audit bean and save
        Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(cfeAudit);

        //2.2 b)Delete the inserted
        Mono<CustomerRequest> delCustomer = bucket1Repository.deleteByLoanAccountId(loanAccountId);
    });

    //Get the loan account id and return the same
    finalResponse = bucket1Repository.findByCustomerId(customerId);
    return Mono.when(externalServiceResponse,customerRequestMono,finalResponse).then(finalResponse)
            .doOnSuccess(resp -> {
                try {
                    finalMasterAudit.setServiceResponse(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(resp));
                    Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(finalMasterAudit);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            })
            .doOnError(error -> {
                try {
                    finalMasterAudit.setServiceResponse(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(error.getMessage()));
                    Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(finalMasterAudit);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });
}
```

Couple issues we observerd are

1. Document is not persisted until we subscribe it in some cases. Is this the expected behavior ? Do we need to subscribe for the document to be saved ?
2. Unable to delete the document in case of error.
3. Also I know I didnt follow pure reactive programming above. Help me with any pointers to write the code effectively in reactive.

Please help us with any pointers

Answer (score 3):

Taking a chunk of the code above:

```
externalServiceResponse.subscribe(response -> {
    Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(cfeAudit);
     }, errorResp -> {
    Mono<CustomerAuditBean> auditResponse = bucket2Repository.save(cfeAudit);
    Mono<CustomerRequest> delCustomer = bucket1Repository.deleteByLoanAccountId(loanAccountId);
});
```

There are two reactive programming issues with it:

1. You are creating Monos that you don't subscribe to, so they will never execute.
2. You shouldn't be creating them in subscribe anyway, but instead using flatMap or onErrorResume to chain them, pre-subscribe.

Something like this should do the trick (forgive me, I haven't tested it so you may need to make some tweaks):

```
externalServiceResponse
   // If something goes wrong then delete the inserted doc
   .onErrorResume(err -> bucket1Repository.deleteByLoanAccountId(loanAccountId))

   // Always want to save the audit regardless
   .then(bucket2Repository.save(cfeAudit))

   .subscribe();
```

There are other problems to fix in the code, e.g. it looks like you want to flatMap multiple Monos together before subscribing to the final Mono, but hopefully this gets you started.